# Methods to simplify array

Tags: php, arrays

Wanting to simplify this array:

```
$week = array(7) { 
[0]=> string(10) "2017-11-05" 
[1]=> string(10) "2017-11-06" 
[2]=> string(10) "2017-11-07" 
[3]=> string(10) "2017-11-08" 
[4]=> string(10) "2017-11-09" 
[5]=> string(10) "2017-11-10" 
[6]=> string(10) "2017-11-11" 
}
```

to:

```
$week = "2017-11-05", "2017-11-06", "2017-11-07", "2017-11-08", "2017-11-09", "2017-11-10", "2017-11-11";
```

and do the same for my $date array

```
$date = array(2) { [0]=> string(10) "2017-11-08" [1]=> string(10) "2017-11-22" }
```

the reason being that I'm trying to find a match in array based on value in another array. Having problems getting in_array to return true.

Example:

```
if  (in_array($date, $week))  {
        echo "No Class!";
    } else { echo "Stuff"; }
```

Comment: Not clear what is the initial array is because it seems that you already have what you want to simplify it to.
Maybe you have an array of `\DateTime` objects in `$week` and want to get an array of formatted dates?

Comment: When do you want the `if` condition to be true? When *all* `$date` entries match, or when *at least one* matches?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your arrays may look complicated because of how `var_dump` outputs them, but they are equivalent to this:

```
$week = ["2017-11-05", "2017-11-06", "2017-11-07", "2017-11-08", "2017-11-09", "2017-11-10", "2017-11-11"];    
$date = ["2017-11-00", "2017-11-22"];
```

With [`array_intersect`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php) you can know whether they have string values in common:

```
if (array_intersect($date, $week)) {
    echo "match";
} else {
    echo "no match";
}
```

In fact, that function returns the intersection as an array, so you can even know from the result which strings are common in both arrays. But if you only need to know whether there is at least one common value, the above `if` condition will do.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying is not valid, because you cannot have multiple strings without an array:

First of all, I would suggest you to check [php-array](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php), to have a better understanding about how arrays work in php.

but I got the idea behind it and a way would be to do it is as follow:

```
$weeks = ["2017-11-05", "2017-11-06", "2017-11-07", "2017-11-08", "2017-11-09", "2017-11-10", "2017-11-11"];
$dates = ["2017-11-08", "2017-11-22"];

$matches = array_map(function($date) use ($weeks) { 
   return in_array($date, $weeks);
}, $dates);

var_dump($matches);
```

See it working [here](https://eval.in/895803):